# how to make an automatic installation disk with a system image (14.04)

Tags: preseed, custom-distributions, remastersys, kickstart, custom-installer

I need to deploy a master PC image to a large number of PCs with the ability to automatically partition disks.

I found how to make a LiveCD from an installed and configured system, but there are no tools for automatic installation - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch
Found how to automate the installation process, but there is no description how to add a master PC image to the image - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

I wanted to make a system image with Remastersys and use the Kickstart file, but the Remastersys image uses ubiquiti, and Kickstart needs a non graphical ubuntu installation ISO (server or alternate installation CD).

Please help.

P.S. used GoogleTranslate to translate

Comment: If the target computers are similar enough, you can **clone an installed system** (for example via a compressed image) and afterwards change the operating system's ID, the user ID and password (or let the final users do it, if they can). An alternative is to create an OEM system, which prompts the final user to fix the final settings, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview

Comment: Thank you, but this option does not fit